# calling a static method from multiple thread, do we need to use the syncronization mechanishm?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am developing a web application in c#, i have to call a static method defined in the Global Class which having access to few Com objects.in this case do i need to protect the Com object ?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question properly? 
Where you want to use syncronisation? What operation you Com object performs?

Comment: I got the same question... Hmmm... I use some static method with a Client. This method gets some data from WCF RIA Services... And I have different Tasks of MS TPL... So I am afraid that could be that the result which returns that static method might be re-writen... So Task#2 will get the data which have been called from the Task#1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on whether the objects that you are using are shared between threads or not. If you create the objects locally in the method, you don't need to synchronise them.

However, depending on what COM object you are using, they might have some limitations. If the object is accessing something that can only be used by one thread at a time, you would have to synchronise the threads so that you only create one instance of the object at once.